# Animate div to top on scroll (as parallax)

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: My website]

I have stacked divs with different colors as in the image, each `div` is having height as 40% of window height, but are set to negative value on top position so creates an illusion of stacked divs.

What I want is to animate these div's on scrolling, i.e. I want to reveal bottom `div`s on scroll and that to scrolling it to large extend with an fixed height of container `div` (set to `height` of window) just like that of parallax effect.

How can I achieve this?

What I have done so far is:

```
var position = $('.panel-wrapper').scrollTop();
$('.panel-wrapper').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
//alert('here');

var scroll = $('.panel-wrapper').scrollTop();
//console.log(scroll);
if (scroll > position) {
    // console.log(parseInt($('.branding-panel').position().top) + parseInt($('.branding-panel').outerHeight(true)));
    // console.log(parseInt(panel_top_position[0]) + parseInt(50));
    if (((parseInt($('.branding-panel').position().top) + parseInt($('.branding-panel').outerHeight(true))) >= (parseInt(panel_top_position[0]) + parseInt(50)))) {
        $('.branding-panel').css('top', parseInt($('.branding-panel').css('top')) - parseInt(100));
    }
    else if (((parseInt($('.advertising-panel').position().top) + parseInt($('.advertising-panel').outerHeight(true))) >= (parseInt(panel_top_position[1]) + parseInt(50)))) {
        $('.advertising-panel').css('top', parseInt($('.advertising-panel').css('top')) - parseInt(200));
    }
    else if (((parseInt($('.interactive-panel').position().top) + parseInt($('.interactive-panel').outerHeight(true))) >= (parseInt(panel_top_position[2]) + parseInt(50)))) {
        $('.interactive-panel').css('top', parseInt($('.interactive-panel').css('top')) - parseInt(300));
    }
    else if (((parseInt($('.films-panel').position().top) + parseInt($('.films-panel').outerHeight(true))) >= (parseInt(panel_top_position[3]) + parseInt(50)))) {
        $('.films-panel').css('top', parseInt($('.films-panel').css('top')) - parseInt(320));
    }

}
else {

}
position = scroll;

});
```

NOTE - I have fixed height as that of my windows and I want to scroll it and reveal other `div`s.

Please help.

Krunal

Comment: can you provide a fiddle link(https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: hi mike, the code is huge..you can view live on http://uat.thecreativevoyage.com.. pls help

Answer (score 0):

Your Code works fine but you need different methods for scroll down and scroll up, this may not be a perfect solution but try this, fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/kq6ko00r/7/

note* adjust values in reset function to fine tune.

```
   function reset() {
  el[0].css({
    top: 0
  });
  el[1].css({
    top: -80
  });
  el[2].css({
    top: -150
  });
  el[3].css({
    top: -230
  });
  el[4].css({
    top: -300
  });
  el[5].css({
    top: -380
  });

};
```

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: want a kind of thing, but it should stack at top one by one..i mean the panels should have position fixed on top when i scroll down..please help

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this code, its very simpler than your code
https://jsfiddle.net/qartal_tr/h67kpaqc/1/

```
.Panel{
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  margin-bottom:-150px;
  box-shadow:0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition:all .5s ease-out;
  top:0px;
}

<div class="Panel" style="background-color:red">
</div>
<div class="Panel" style="background-color:green">
</div>
<div class="Panel" style="background-color:purple">
</div>
<div class="Panel" style="background-color:yellow">
</div>
<div class="Panel" style="background-color:lightblue">
</div>
<div class="Panel" style="background-color:darkgreen">
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var Z = 10000;
  $(".Panel").each(function(){
    $(this).css("z-index", Z--);
  });

  $(window).scroll(function(e){
    $(".Panel").each(function(){
        var ScrollHeight = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if(ScrollHeight < 0 && $(this).css("top") == "0px")
          $(this).css("top", "-150px");
        else if(ScrollHeight >= -150 && $(this).css("top") == "-150px")
          $(this).css("top", "0px");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome one... Saeed can you please help me by making this panels sticked at top while scrolling down..i.e. one by one it will be stacked at top with small height...

Comment: so it wasnt what you looking for? :-)

Comment: it is a solution to me, but need an stack on top.. but anyways thanks for the help...